# retrieve timestamp value properly from cassandra in node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra

in my database I have timestamp value like this:

```
2015-06-25 11:39:17+0530
```

but after retrieving it's like:

```
2015-06-25T06:19:13.362Z
```

....so how to retrieve it in the correct format.

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test.tab (
key text,
time timestamp,
value decimal,
PRIMARY KEY (key, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX key_index_tab ON test.tab (time);
```

and node.js code for retrieval:

```
var selectQuery='select * from tab where key=? and time>? and time<? allow filtering;';
Cclient.execute(selectQuery,[key,fromdate,partTodate],function(err, result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Cassandra timestamp and [Ecmascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) represent a single moment in time (without timezone information), so the date stored and retrieved is the same but you are seeing differences in the string representation of the date.

You can use [Date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to string represent it in another way or change the UTC offset.